# issue during google sheet macro

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an issue with this google sheet macro. Error message is: Exception: Range not found
I am trying to perform this script in order to copy recipient string (that can change according to data in P2 cell.
Can you help me?

Thanks

```
function macro() 
{ 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("A2:L1000"); 
  var data = dataRange.getValues(); 
  for (i in data) 
    { 
      var rowData = data[i]; 
      var recipient = rowData[0];    
      var parameter1 = rowData[1];  
      if (parameter1 == "OK") 
      { 
        sheet.getRange('P2').activate();
        sheet.getRange(recipient).copyTo(sheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's in rowData[0]? Perhaps a range in A1 notation?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you want:

```
function macro() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rg = sh.getRange("A2:L1000");
  var data = rg.getValues();
  data.forEach((r,i)=>{
    if(r[1] == "OK") {
      sh.getRange(r[0]).copyTo(sh.getRange(i + 2, 16),SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made something like this but it is only copy/paste first row (copy B2 to P2 works fine).
If I try to copy B3 to P2 it does not work..

```
  function macro() 
  { 
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange("A2:L1000"); 
    var data = dataRange.getValues(); 
    for (i in data) 
      { 
        var rowData = data[i]; 
        var parameter1 = rowData[10];  
        if (parameter1 == "OK") 
        { 
          sheet.getRange('P2').activate();
          sheet.getRange("B" +(i+2)).copyTo(sheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
        }
      }
  }
```